# Get selected option from html via php

Tags: php, html

I have a simple simple question, And is so strange for me.
In my `HTML` file I have a button and a `form tag` in which used `select tag` with some `options` as :

```
<form action="" method="post" name="general"> Wireless mode
   <select name="wirelessmode" id="wirelessmode">
     <option value="ap">AP</option>
     <option value="client">Client</option>
     <option value="clientbrdige">Client Bridge(Routed)</option>
     <option value="adhoc">Adhoc</option>
     <option value="wdsstation">WDS Station</option>
     <option value="wdsap">WDS AP</option>   
   </select> <br>
</form>

<form action="" method="post" name="apply">
   <input type="submit" name="apply" value="Apply"/>
</form>
```

Include that `HTML` file in my `Php` file, create a class and a function to display the selected option of the `HTML` as below :

```
<?php
   include('./view/config.html');
      class SSHCommand{
         public function display(){
            if (isset($_POST['apply'])) // press button {
                $category = $_POST['wirelessmode']; // get the select option
                echo $category;
            }            
        }
     }
     $sshCommand=new SSHCommand();   
     $sshCommand->display();
?>
```

When i try, it gives me nothing !
But when i try :

```
echo 'david';
```

instead of

```
echo $category;
```

It prints david after press apply button.
Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: you'll need to include your html as a php file

Comment: please format your code correctly when posting. There is a tidy function in http://phpfiddle.org/ and http://jsfiddle.net (javascript). Even the snippet tool on stackoverflow has a tidy function. It makes the code a lot more decipherable!

Comment: Also, please take the time to read the tour. I see you've asked a couple of questions before, and received answers but not accepted them. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer - hover and click - it's not hard and you gain rep for accepting answers!

Comment: posting thank yous is not the go-by method of thanking people on SO. With 15 rep you can vote up helpful answers, and even with any rep you can accept answers [aswell as upvote]. Please upvote your helpful answers and accept an answer. Hover beside the answer you choose to accept and click the checkmark that appears. It will turn green. You get 2 points, the answerer gets 15. Upvotes award 10 points. You can upvote as many as you like but you can only accept one answer per question

Comment: Btw, even though you can only accept one answer, you can still upvote the others if you wish...

Comment: @RachelGallen: I appreciate it. 
:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to include your config.html as html with a php extension .. config.php for the html include to work.. that would be a key thing.

You can include HTML or text in a PHP include file. Anything that can go in an standard HTML file can go in a PHP include.

Your entire website should be subsequently saved using .php extensions however, whether they include php or not, that's the downside, eg. index.php rather than index.html, so it could be time-consuming. **Some servers don't require this**, so test your configuration first.

Best of luck

Comment: So you mean I embed the html file codes into the Php file?
I copy and paste them in top of the start <?php 
?

Comment: yes exactly, php goes in the body of a html doc (in php tags) but you can also put plain ol' html in there too, handy, eh?

Comment: welcome to the world of php by the way! it's glorious!! :)

Answer (score 2):

you can get a result using single FORM, modified your HTML code as per bellow.

```
 <form action="" method="post" name="general" id="general_form"> Wireless mode
    <select name="wirelessmode" id="wirelessmode">
      <option value="ap">AP</option>
      <option value="client">Client</option>
      <option value="clientbrdige">Client Bridge(Routed)</option>
      <option value="adhoc">Adhoc</option>
      <option value="wdsstation">WDS Station</option>
      <option value="wdsap">WDS AP</option>   
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="apply" value="Apply"/>
</form>
```

Comment: But I do not want this,
For this question I omitted other form.
The submit button is at the end of the html page.

Comment: Your input element and Submit button should be in same FORM element without that you will never get the form data using GET or POST method.

Answer (score 0):

Your select is in one form block and the submit button is in another. The default nature of the submit button will submit only the html elements in that form and not all forms of the page. So to get this to work, you need to keep one form with the required elements as

```
<form action="" method="post" name="general"> Wireless mode
<select name="wirelessmode" id="wirelessmode">
<option value="ap">AP</option>
<option value="client">Client</option>
<option value="clientbrdige">Client Bridge(Routed)</option>
<option value="adhoc">Adhoc</option>
<option value="wdsstation">WDS Station</option>
<option value="wdsap">WDS AP</option>   
</select> <br>
<input type="submit" name="apply" value="Apply"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Apologies. I missed them.

Comment: @RachelGallen : I am male :-D
And brand new to Php.
Thanks to all Php community.